How can I get the title of the currently open GUI in Minecraft Forge MDK 1.12.2?
I'm working on a Forge mod for Minecraft version 1.12.2 and I need to retrieve the title of the currently open GUI. In newer versions like Forge MDK 1.16.5, I can achieve this using mc.screen.getTitle() where mc represents Minecraft.getInstance(). However, in Forge MDK 1.12.2, the getTitle() function is not available in mc.currentScreen. Can anyone suggest an alternative method or workaround to get the title of the opened GUI in this version?
I have already attempted to explore the Minecraft source code to find a solution, but unfortunately, I have not been successful. Any insights or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
